# Inserting FK values in Entity Framework that already exist (identical entries) in one table without updating the primary key of another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, relational-database

I recently asked a question related to this and found a solution, but realized I may have a bigger problem. If anyone can tell me if I'm able to do what I describe below without making changes to the database it would be greatly appreciated! **Note**: I'm new to Entity Framework.

I am trying to insert into this table [(Agreement Settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAgGF.png) duplicate `SettingsId` values for a new agreement (associated with an `agreementId` that is illustrated in the table as a column).

However, a `SettingsId` is also stored in a table with these columns [Algorithm Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5itkV.png). The Id column represents a `SettingsId` and is the primary key of this table.

I only want to update the `Agreement Settings` table (the former table above) with these new duplicate `SettingsId` values and leave the latter table alone.  That way I will have agreements that have duplicate `SettingsId` guids but only one unique representation of that guid in the `Algorithm Settings` table.

When I try to insert into the database using Entity Framework:

```
dataTransferAgreement = (await _dataTransferContext.Agreements
                        .AddAsync(dataTransferAgreement))
                        .Entity;
```

I get brand new guids for `SettingsIds` returned, although the object `dataTransferAgreement` has the duplicate guids as properties beforehand (they are replaced). I assume this is because Entity Framework sees these foreign keys in `Agreement Settings` table and their association to `Algorithm Settings` table (the primary key) and automatically updates the primary key and thus the associated foreign keys on its own.

I of course can't add the `Algorithm Settings` table properties to `dataTransferAgreement`, as that would cause a primary key conflict.

**The question**: is there any way to manually (or otherwise) insert these duplicate foreign key values into `Agreement Settings` table without touching the `Algorithm Settings` table in Entity Framework (code first)? Currently, the entity property that inserts the primary key Id for `SettingsId` is decorated with  `[Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, which is used in numerous other places in this project, so I assume I cannot change that.

Also, the entity property that associates this table in the code:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(SettingsId))]
public AlgorithmSetting AlgorithmSetting { get; set; }
```

is not needed in my case (since I don't want to do anything with it), but I can't just remove it due to it being a domain model (again, I'm an Entity Framework newbie so if I'm wrong in any way please correct me).

Answer (score 0):

In your agreements settings table, add a primary key "id", alongside the other two columns you already have. Entity Framework and relational databases aren't going to support the same primary key.

If you need to query the agreement table in the future, you can do so with any column values and just "ignore" the new primary key you added.

Happy to help further if needed.

Comment: That is a simple way to do this with database changes.  One I have not thought of previously.  Would that not effect other areas of the application using that table though? 
This is a large project and I am just adding my small part. I'm also trying to figure out if I can get away with not making any changes to the database schema.  Perhaps I have to?